When I am Using Einstein bot with embedded service, bot are not opening up, It is showing when I drag Lightning Message service component in community
I have created an Einstein Bot. Its preview works as expected in Bot Builder. Then I have added it to Community as Embedded Service Deployment but It is not opening up.
What are the steps we are missing, can someone suggest?

